# Argument of type 'Alias' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'

Tags: angular, typescript

When I updated angular version now I got error like in subject.
How should I fix this?

I got interface like:

```
export interface Alias {
    nr?: number;
    local_part?: string;
    domain?: string;
    recipients?: string;
    username?: string;
    changes?: string;
    action?: string;
    old_alias?: string;
}
```

in my component.ts

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  alias: Alias
```

and there I want to get data from backend

```
  this.aliasesService.getAlias(params).subscribe(
    res => {
      var result = Object.keys(res).map(function (key) {
        return [Number(key), res[key]];
      });
      this.alias = res;
      },
    err => console.error(err)
  );
```

There is error message

```
ERROR in src/app/home/home.component.html:154:44 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Alias' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'.

Type 'Alias' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
    
154 *ngFor="let aliases of alias | filterBy: queryString | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p }; let i = index">
```

Comment: **It's just a typo**. You have `this.alias = res;` where I assume you mean `this.alias = result;` in your `subscribe` callback. Otherwise, there's no point in building `result`.

Comment: When I do this.alias = result there is an error: Type any[][] has no properties in common with type 'Alias'

Comment: Well, that makes sense. `result` is an array. `alias` isn't. So TypeScript is doing its job. You're converting `res` (whatever that is) to an array of `[number, ???]` (e.g., `Array<[number, ???]>` or `([number, ???])[]`). How does that relate to `alias`?

Comment: this result was just for test.
this.alias = res
console.log(this.alias) is Object object

Answer (score 1):

It's probably happenning because on your service, you set the return as `Observable<any[]>`, instead of array, remove the brackets, then it will be like that:
`Observable<any>`

Comment: It looks like:   getAlias(nr: string): Observable<Alias> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.API_URI}/aliases/edit/${nr}`);
  }

Comment: But it is fetching more than one Alias at time? If so, add the brackets like `Alias[]`

Comment: it fetching only one response based on nr

Comment: So that's the problem, you should not use *ngFor, like `*ngFor="let aliases of alias` , the HTML is expecting a list on alias

Comment: This error is from:

  getAliases() {
    this.aliasesService.getAliases().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.alias = res;
      },
      err => console.error(err)
    );
  }

There is 400 records

Comment: Well, so I resugest for you to change the return to Observable<Alias[]>